# Scaling of UIView break constraint

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview

How to scale properly UIView which is loaded from xib and have UIlabels, UIImageView etc. with constraints.

Here is a code how I scale it:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:aDuration
                      delay:aDelay
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{

                     aCardView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(aZoom, aZoom);

                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                 }];
```

As result I receive warnings and UIImageView inside scales incorrectly

But when I scale the same UIView which is loaded from UIViewController it works well and there is no warnings.

Here are warnings I receive:

```
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x13aeca670 h=-&- v=-&- FFCardView:0x13af8e840.width == FFCardsCollectionView:0x13700a380.width - 129>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x13705adc0 FFCardsCollectionView:0x13700a380.trailing == UITableView:0x1360a6400.trailing>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x13706bc90 FFCardsCollectionView:0x13700a380.leading == UITableView:0x1360a6400.leading>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x13705c460 H:|-(0)-[UITableView:0x1360a6400]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x135f4dfb0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x13705c4b0 H:[UITableView:0x1360a6400]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x135f4dfb0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x13ade45d0 H:[UIImageView:0x13af0ac90(300)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x13af9a0f0 H:|-(0)-[UIImageView:0x13af0ac90]   (Names: '|':FFCardView:0x13af8e840 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x13af9a140 H:[UIImageView:0x13af0ac90]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':FFCardView:0x13af8e840 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x135fe6f00 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UIView:0x135f4dfb0(375)]>"
```

Comment: Does the view from UIViewController has the same constraints as the one from xib?

Comment: yes. it has the same constrains

Comment: And what does the warnings say? Also what iOS version are you testing it on?

Comment: Updated topic with warnings list. I've been using iOS 9.3

Answer (score 0):

The issue that I see from the warnings you provided is that you are trying to scale your view to a size that conflicts with the constraints. For instance, you have a `ImageView` with leading and trailing margins and a `300 width`. If you try to scale your view to a size with width smaller than `300` your constraints will break and so will your layout. When scaling always have in mind the constraints that your view has because they do NOT scale with the view. You can of course modify the constraint when scaling, this is another solution. It depends on your need really.

Comment: I can't not setting width for UIImageView in Interface Builder because will have errors. Should I call [self updateConstrains] every time want to scale UIView?

Comment: Well the warning above says that you already have a width set in Interface Builder of `300`. Calling ` [self updateConstrains] ` doesn't help because it updates the changes in constraints but you do not change them anywhere so it doesn't do anything.